# JavaScript: How to make an alert dialog appear when clicking an SVG element?

Tags: javascript, svg, addeventlistener

I am having trouble getting an event listener to work for click event's on SVG elements in my web page.

Right now, it is displaying the first dialog whenever the page loads (the title of `cercle`). What I want it to do is display the alert message only when that particular SVG element (or section) of the SVG image is clicked. I also what the alert to display if the an SVG element is clicked again.

Please help as I am really stumped on this one.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
const cercle = document.getElementById('leCercle');
const rectangle = document.getElementById("leRect");
const path = document.getElementById("laCourbe");

cercle.addEventListener("click" , showCercleTitle());
path.addEventListener("click" , showPathTitle());
rectangle.addEventListener("click" , showRectTitle());
```

The `id` and references are correct, as it is displaying the correct titles, but only once and for the `cercle` and then nothing else.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not `cercle.addEventListener(onclick(showCercleTitle()));`. It's `circle.addEventListener("click", showCercleTitle);` And, that's assuming that `circle` is an element that even has a `click` event.

Comment: Ah ok! I fixed that part, but it's still not working...

Comment: Because, as I said, `circle` (or whatever you are using `addEventListener` on) has to have the event you are listening for. If not, it's like waiting around for a cat to bark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the issue with your code is the `()` after each of your event handlers, when passing then to `addEventListener()`. Take for instance the `cercle` SVG element and `showCercleTitle()` handler:

```
cercle.addEventListener("click" , showCercleTitle()); //<-- () causing the issue
```

By passing `showCercleTitle()` with `()`, you're calling the `showCercleTitle` function immediately when passing it to `addEventListener()` as the `click` event handler. This means that the result of that call to `showCercleTitle()` (which is probably `undefined`?) is what will be used as the handler for the `click` event on the SVG element. To resolve this issue, consider removing the `()` on all event handler assignments, as shown below:

```js
const cercle = document.getElementById('leCercle');
const rectangle = document.getElementById("leRect");
const path = document.getElementById("laCourbe");

/* Define callback functions for each alert/dialog */
function showCercleTitle() {
  alert('showCercleTitle')
}

function showPathTitle() {
  alert('showPathTitle')
}

function showRectTitle() {
  alert('showRectTitle')
}

/* Add each defined callback as click event listener to
respective svg elements. Avoid adding the () after each
handler when passing to addEventListener() */
cercle.addEventListener("click", showCercleTitle);
path.addEventListener("click", showPathTitle);
rectangle.addEventListener("click", showRectTitle);
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <rect id="laCourbe" x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
  <rect id="leRect" x="60" y="10" rx="10" ry="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
  <circle id="leCercle" cx="25" cy="75" r="20" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>  
</svg>
```

Comment: The `()` were a syntax problem, but that's not the real issue. The OP is trying to register a `click` event on an object that doesn't have a `click` event.

Comment: I don't see anything on that link relating to any supported events. You linked to *methods*. Methods are not events. [This may help](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/svg-interaction-pointer-events-property/).

Comment: @ScottMarcus oh sorry about that - I should have been clearer. The content of the link I sent you reads: `SVGElement` "inherits methods from its parent, Element" . The `SVGElement` therefore provides the `addEventListener()`, through which the `click` event can be "handled" on the corresponding `SVGElement` instance

Comment: You misunderstand. No one is disputing whether it has `.addEventListner`. The question is whether it has a `click` event.

Comment: Interesting - seems to be working as expected for me

Comment: Yes, but is it standard? Will it work cross-browser?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point - perhaps a bit more specificity in the OP around cross-browser requirements would be helpful here

Comment: IMHO It's 2019 - everything should be cross-browser, standards-based code. ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus it seems like that was the issue! Everything is working fine now! I've tested it on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Edge and it works ok on all of them!

Comment: @LorenzoBattilocchi That's great. But understand that just because it work in all of them doesn't make it standard. If it's not standard, it could break tomorrow.

Comment: @LorenzoBattilocchi glad I could help :)